# Access Amazon QLDB in Spring boot application

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-qldb

is there a way to access Amazon QLDB as a repository in spring boot applications like MongoDB?

Comment: Could you please link to documentation for the mongodb feature you talk about and provide more context please?

Comment: Can you please tell how can we connect to QLDB in Spring boot?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a library yet that integrates QLDB with spring boot.

Answer (score 0):

I started to look at building exactly what you suggest, I even contacted the lead of spring data to look at adding this (I haven’t raised the ticket yet), however the CrudRepository interface provided enough integration for the demo applications that we have built with Spring Boot. One of the issues that i had when trying to create the Repository was the mapping of fields from the java objects into the partiql fields without explicit knowledge of what was changing.

QLDB does not have a jdbc driver anymore so it is now a proprietary driver which also uses partiql over sql, there could be some further issues getting this to work as a full blown repository in spring boot due to the inner reliance on sql in spring data .

Comment: How can we connect to QLDB in Spring boot?